# interact elements with dynamic label in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Python newbie here.  All of 1 month old.  Most of the elements in page i am trying to scrape, i am able to handle them and interact with them.  there are two elements that have dynamic labels which i am not able to handle.  The source page looks as below

```
<span class="a-button-inner">
   <input class="a-button-input" type="submit" aria-labelledby="Ae8MCi-55">
   <span id="Ae8MCi-55" class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true">Add Your Key</span>
</span>
```

Upon each refresh the label is new so i cannot get a fixed XPATH of that.  There are multiple items with span class "a-button-inner" as well as input class "a-button-input" and there are other submit buttons as well in the rest of the page.  The only thing unique is the Span text "Add Your Key".

Appreciate all help to get the submit button element and to click/submit it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
.
.
.
.
# objAddKey = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Ae8MCi-55"]/span/input') does not work as second round its a different XPath
objAddKey = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Add Your Key') # hoping this will get a sibling and then to get the parent and then look for all the children.  I don't even know if its possible in python.
objAddKey.click()'
```

Tried to search for searching by span text, and came across some other stuff,
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-text-found-between-span-selenium

```
WebElement l = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p/span"));
String s = l.getText();
```

but this does not help either.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html
went through this, but not much help either.

Appreciate your help and pointers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Add Your Key` is unique then you can use the below xpath :

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Add Your Key')]//preceding-sibling::input[@class='a-button-input']
```

or even without class :

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Add Your Key')]//preceding-sibling::input
```

and use it like this :

```
objAddKey = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Add Your Key')]//preceding-sibling::input")
objAddKey.click()
```

I would suggest you to have explicit waits for more reliability.

[Selenium - Python - Explicit waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: Thank you .... this worked like a charm ....  however there is another issue ...  i will create a new thread for that ... as it may be something others may also face.

Comment: following this page, i arrived at another page and it has some interesting stuff that has gotten my stumped so far.  here is that question,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68248694/enter-credit-card-data-in-python-selenium