# Enter Credit Card Data in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is question follows another question I asked earlier

[Dynamic element details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68237739/interact-elements-with-dynamic-label-in-python-selenium/68237902#68237902)

I am trying to use Python and Selenium to arrive at a page and enter Credit Card data.  Unlike the earlier question where the field had dynamic properties, this field has a static name, meaning I can find the element by name, and input some data, it seems I am missing something big here.  Here are the page details:

```
<input type="tel" id=cc-yN0P6v-14" autocomplete="off" name="txtCrdtCrdNum" class="a-input-text">
```

and my selenium code looks like this

```
objCrdNumber = driver.find_element_by_name('txtCrdtCrdNum')
objCrdNumber.send_keys(UserData.CrdtCrdNumber)
```

I get the error message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

That's when I realised the input in of type tel. I wonder what that has got to do with anything.  But I am stumped out of this.

### Update

A big thank you to @Prophet.  Walked the extra mile and walked along with me till the issue was resolved.  We were missing a iFrame that was not visible in the area we were looking.

Comment: Does it work if you use the xpath instead of the static name?

Comment: No as the XPath is also dynamic generated upon each refresh.

Comment: Probably a long shot, but try clicking objCrdNumber before sending the credit card number to it.

Comment: @Vinod did you try my answer?

Comment: @Prophet yes i did.  I commented for the same for the answer post.  basically its giving a timeout error.

Comment: Can you share the full error stack?

Comment: how do i do that ....   newB here ...  started Python abt a month ago.  When i tried here it said too long for comment ..... will try split ....

Comment: @itronic1990 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "....\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "..../TestCCrdData.py", line 129, in <module>

Comment: @itronic1990 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "..../TestCCrdData.py", line 129, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 200).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'txtCrdtCrdNum'))).send_keys(UserData.CrdtCrdNumber)
  File "....\PYTHON_SERVER\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @Vinod : Are you launching the browser in full mode  ?

Comment: @crisepandey yes i am

Comment: Is the site publicly accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ElementNotInteractableException` means that you trying to access an element that is currently not interactable.
This can be caused by several causes.

1. Element is not visible since it is out of the view.
2. Element is still not fully rendered.
3. Some other element is currently covering this element.
   maybe something other, but similar to the above.
   Since I can't know what causes your problem in your specific case you can try one of the following and it should work.

1. To bring the element into view try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

actions = ActionChains(driver)
objCrdNumber = driver.find_element_by_name('txtCrdtCrdNum')
actions.move_to_element(objCrdNumber).build().perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
objCrdNumber.send_keys(UserData.CrdtCrdNumber)
```

2. to wait for the element is fully rendered try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "txtCrdtCrdNum"))).send_keys(UserData.CrdtCrdNumber)
```

**UPD**
Your element is inside iframe.
You have to switch to that iframe in order to access elements inside it.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@class,'secure')]"))
```

When finished with that form don't forget to switch to the default content with

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: I hope one of the above methods will help. In case is still doesn't - I will try giving more ideas.

Comment: Instead of using `EC.visibility_of_element_located` I usually use `EC.element_to_be_clickable` - slower, but more foolproof, especially since the OP needs to click in the area.

Comment: here we are dealing with element no interactable. One of the main things causing this exception - the element is out of the view. In this case element will obviously not clickable. As well as not visible.

Comment: @Prophet Thank you for the support.  Unfortunately it does not work.  I tried EC.element_to_be_clickable with a wait of 20, 100, all the way to 200.  I keep getting a timeout error.  selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
python-BaseException.

Comment: OK, did you try the first approach, move to element with actions? Also, please share your code. It may be very useful.

Comment: @Prophet AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'build'

Comment: If so you can use it without build() `actions.move_to_element(objCrdNumber).perform()`

Comment: @Prophet  new error `raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: [object HTMLInputElement] has no size and location`

Comment: while the page was open and code was waiting i tried to manually click on the text box to get focus, but still no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234520/discussion-between-vinod-and-prophet).